# What encoding to use in python 3.5 to get an ascii extended set up to 255

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, pyqt5, pyserial

I am working with pyserial. To send data I am converting my input from a QPlainTextEdit widget. I was using 'ascii' encoding on the input before sending. This all seemed fine until I took in characters above 127. I now that this is the range for the 'ascii' encoding. I solved the issue creating a bytearray() like so

```
    chars = []
    for c in s:
        chars.append(ord(c))
    chars = list(map(int, chars))
```

I am just wondering is there a way of doing this using a different encoding. So i can just use, `s.encode('')`

I have played around 'Latin-1', and few others but its not what I am after. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Point taken, to be honest I have not required in depth knowledge of Unicode to date (not a high level programmer). I will soon however so it's time to read. The serial tool mentioned above is not a professional application. It's just something whipped up, to talk to a piece of hardware that uses tailored fonts (hand produced bitmaps ranging up 0xFF). I was using OC-Console but had no way to automate the sending of multiple packets, thus this venture. Cheers

Comment: @10SecTom. A textual representation implies some sort of translation layer - i.e. an encoding/decoding mechanism that maps bytes in the range 0-255 to some unicode code point. If you use a standard single-byte encoding (such as latin1/iso8859-1 or windows-1252) you would have to use characters such as `©` to represent the hex value `0xA9` (for example). Otherwise, you would need to enter the actual hex values as text (e.g. `68 65 6C 6C 6F`) and then parse this into integer values that can be converted to bytes. So, essentially, create a crude hex editor.

Comment: @10SecTom. PS: The parser could be a simple as: `bytes(int(x, 16) for x in 'A9 68 65 6C 6C 6F'.split())`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Cheers for the help.